# HTTP-запрос на сервер, с использованием curl на с++

Tags: c++, vkontakte-api, curl

Пишу свою библиотеку для работы с [vk-api](https://vk.com/dev) на с++. В общем у меня есть запрос такого вида:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=здесь_айди&random_id=0&message=сообщение&access_token=здесь_токен&v=5.50
```

При чем сам запрос - рабочий. Имеется вот такой код:

```
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=здесь_айди&random_id=0&message=сообщение&access_token=здесь_токен&v=5.50");
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Программа компилируется, но ничего не происходит и никакого сообщения не приходит, не могли  бы вы мне помочь разобраться в этом? Заранее спасибо за помощь:)

Comment: curl_easy_perform???

Comment: @こきん, извините забыл добавить в вопрос

Comment: Угу, а теперь вот на этот код посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1077524/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-curl-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-connection-close в основном на CURLOPT_URL

Comment: @こきん, получается вместо `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` нужно использовать `CURLOPT_URL`?

Comment: Да, и вам стоит прочитать документацию к библиотеке.

Comment: @こきん, благодарю,  позже попробую поменять и документацию по подробнее изучу, видимо что-то не дополнял:)

Comment: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html